# Is there any way to change the structure of urls in Shopify?

Tags: seo, shopify

Is there any way to change the actual structure of a url in Shopify, rather than just the handle? For instance if I add a product it will be available at the following urls:

- `/products/some-product`
- `/collections/collection-name/products/some-product`

Is there any way I could change this to `/collection-name/some-product`, i.e. remove unnecessary words from the url?

I also realise you can add redirects, but this isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1):

When thinking on the product page you should never think of playing or using the url which has 'collections'. If you take a deep look on the source code of a product you'll realize they all have a rel canonical tag pointing to the

> ../products/some-product

even if the product is displayed within the url

> ../collections/collection-name/products/some-product

If the collections url doesn't have that canonical tag, use it, otherwise crawlers/robots would consider it duplicate content because 2 different urls would show the same content.

Then if you're ok with the first part, you'll only have

> ../products/some-product

In such case, you will never be able to change the

> ../products/

part. But this is good as it helps [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/) store owners maintain a really well structured organization of products.

If you still for some reason need to play hard with urls, you can deep a bit into [Application Proxies](https://docs.shopify.com/api/uiintegrations/application-proxies/).

Comment: I disagree that it's "good". If anything it's simply limiting, hurts SEO, and prevents you from being able to hide that "Shopify feel". For me, it's a reason to not recommend Shopify. The correct answer, apparently, is a custom site that doesn't live on their servers and instead uses Shopify's API to pull in data, since what the OP really wants to do is impossible within their ecosystem.